# Move content of each sub-subdirectory to folder

Tags: powershell

I have a folder structure where in `Folder1` there's subdirectories where each contains a subdirectory of the same name again. From that directory I want to move all subdirectories into `Folder0`. There's subdirectories of the same name, so their content shall be moved to the according subdirectory in `Folder0`.

For example:

`Folder1/Fotos Teil 1 von 178/Fotos Teil 1 von 178/Photos/*` shall be moved to `Folder0/Photos/*`

This is the structure

```
Folder0
├─Photos
├─Memories
├─Albums and Favorites
│
Folder1
├─Fotos Teil 1 von 178
│ └─Fotos Teil 1 von 178
│   ├─Photos
│   ├─Memories
│   └─Albums and Favorites
│
├─Fotos Teil 2 von 178
│ └─Fotos Teil 2 von 178
│   ├─Photos
│   ├─Memories
│   └─Albums and Favorites
╎
.
.
.
╎
├─Fotos Teil 178 von 178
│ └─Fotos Teil 178 von 178
│   ├─Photos
│   └─Albums and Favorites
```

I understand that this is probably a job for PowerShell. I have only worked with bash scripts, but this needs to be done in Windows.

Comment: so you want all the files in the deeper `photos` dirs moved to the  top level `photos` dir? and the same to be done for the other dirs at the deeper level?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Move all the folders within "Folder1/foo/foo/" to "Folder0". If they already exist (like 'Photos'), move the containing files.

Comment: when you use `Get-ChildItem` to load a directory info object, you can use the `.Parent` property to find the parent dir. you can do `.Parent.Parent` to get the two parent dirs ... and then compare them. if they are the same, you have one of your double-named dirs. ///// however, a simpler way may be to just grab any dir with the desired name that is NOT at the top level.

Answer (score 2):

Here a short snippet (not tested!).
Might that one helps you for the logic and how to do this in PowerShell.

```
$Source = '.\Folder1'
$Destination = '.\Folder0'

foreach ($Folder in (Get-ChildItem -Path ($Source + '\*\*\'))) #For each folder -> Photos / Memories / Albums and Favorites
{
    foreach ($Item in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.FullName)) #Get all items
    {
        Move-Item -Path $Item.FullName -Destination ($Destination + '\' + $Folder.Name) #Move the items
    }
}
```